# Is there a service, besides SASS, that darkens CSS colors and gives you the hexadecimal code?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a service that allows you to enter a hexadecimal code for a color and a desired percentage of darkening. The service then returns the hexadecimal code of the new color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use plain ol' [`HSV` colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Type your HEX color into the top box of [this website](http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx)  and slide the `value` slider to darken/lighten the color to your desire.

`HSV` is quite useful for making shades of a certain `RGB` color, as changing a `100` to a `90` is all you need to do to darken a color a little.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you mean by "a service", [0to255.com](http://0to255.com) may give you what you want.

You choose a colour and it presents you with a range of colours and their numeric code (quote: "from black to white using an interval optimized for web design. Then, just click the variation you want to use and the hex code is automatically copied to your clipboard").

Alternately, I write my CSS in SASS (http://www.sass-lang.com) these days which compiles down to CSS, and amongst the benefits are the fact that it supports various colour manipulation functions such as "lighten" and "darken" (eg 'color: darken(#ab280e, 15%)') so you can just code up your style with what you want and let SASS do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another "service" is Colorglower - [Get lighter and darker shade of hex color](http://colorglower.com) Youcan use this tool to generate lighter and darker shades of hex color. You can even adjust the shade percentage of the hex value